# How to input formula to right of the last row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Please see below table, I want to put subtotals 1 rows down from the last row. This has worked well for row C and D (using the below code), however the rest of the columns wont always have info in every row.

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Formula = "=sum(C1:C" & lastrow & ")"
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(lastrow + 1, 4).Formula = "=sum(D1:D" & lastrow & ")"
```

How can I insert a formula to the right of my other subtotals (highlighted in yellow) as I need them all on the same row?

[image: Table]

Comment: You can either use `OffSet` or as you already have the row you want to enter the totals in,  just increment the column value in: `Cells(lastrow + 1, 4).Formula`. So to set the value for column `E`: `Cells(lastrow + 1, 5).Formula`. More importantly, how do you know how many columns need the total? If the columns will be static, you can have a `FOR` loop to fill the values. If they are dynamic, you will have to get column count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use one column to determine the last row (Using `Column A` here)

Also, the bottom of your sum range is indicated by the last row (`LR`), but where you want your formulas to go is 2 rows below (hence the `LR + 2`)

---

```
Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update
Dim LR as Long

LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("C" & LR + 2).Formula = "=Sum(C2:C" & LR & ")"
ws.Range("D" & LR + 2).Formula = "=Sum(D2:D" & LR & ")"
```

Comment: Might be worth just adding the `+2` when you get the row count. You then don't need to have `+2` every time you want to add a formula

Comment: Then you need to use `LR - 2` when doing the formula. Or another variable could be set with `LR - 2`. Either way, the variable is used to determine 2 separate locations here (sum range and location of formula on sheet) so it doesn't just end at setting `LR.Offset(2)`. This way seemed more intuitive. If there was a lot more code to follow, I would justify a second variable maybe

Comment: @urdearboy you could write the whole formulas in one line: `ws.Range("C" & LR + 2 & ":J" & LR + 2).Formula = "=Sum(C2:C" & LR & ")"`

Comment: Brilliant! I knew it was something simple, I was just overthinking it too much. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, Column As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For Column = 3 To 10
            .Cells(LastRow + 2, Column) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(2, Column), Cells(LastRow, Column)))
        Next Column

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Worth to mention that this calculates the sum in VBA and **does not reflect any later changes in data** until the sum row is deleted manually and the code is run again. Calculating the sum in VBA versus writing a formula with VBA end up in 2 completly different approaches.

Comment: Additionally, if you make changes and run the code again you will have issue with the Last row calculation.